# Read-only peer-review mode for mods cross-domain

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderator-abilities

Consider this:

I am currently a pro-tem mod on <shame less="plug">http://dba.stackexchange.com</shame> and I want to get (for instance) [@ChrisF](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/47/chrisf) to review a pending moderation item, since he's a moderator on http://programmers.stackexchange.com. It would be nice if there were a way to give him a URL or something to get a second opinion on what I'm looking at.

I realize that:

- there are some other issues to be considered here, for instance, how do we limit what mods can or can't see on another site, but is that really a requirement?
- we have the RCtrio for just this sort of thing, and we can always ping a dev via chat.

But this would be really handy for putting the moderation in the hands of the community even more than it already is.

Comment: I have to vote this up as I was the one who suggested it on chat ;)

Comment: @ChrisF ~ it was a damned fine suggestion. Also: you snooze you lose :p

Comment: I have more than enough rep here anyway ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure I see the upside here.

So, you and Chris are in the moderator chat, and there's a moderator flag that you want to have him look at.  Rather than needing him to look at the actual flag, you can just link him to the post in the chat.  It can be discussed in chat just fine then.

Maybe you want Chris to look at a user annotation.  You need to coordinate with him in chat anyway, so why not just say something like *"this user has previously been annotated because `<x>` and now has this post `<link>`, so what do you think?"*

It just seems like no matter what you have to coordinate via chat, so what does this offer that you aren't already doing via chat?

Comment: Don't you see this is just a plot by @ChrisF and me to become moderators **everywhere**?

Comment: Keeps things off the transcript to reduce further confusion. Shows which users may be involved in flags. Shows language users may have used during flagging that some mods may turn up their nose at and whine about. Allows the community to self-mod more than we can currently and anything that's about encouraging the community to self-police more is a net-win in Jeff's diatribes. Because Ivo needs to be a mod everywhere ;)

Comment: @IvoFlipse: that would be awesome if he was....

Comment: So for the interim (Cos I know rchern has read my reply) I'm marking this answered, but it would be cool if it became [status-completed] one day ...