# Annotate user accounts network-wide when they get rate-limited or banned

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, moderators, post-ban

A while back, I proposed giving moderators limited [moderation privileges on closely related sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105281/provide-limited-observer-mod-status-to-moderators-on-closely-related-sites), but it didn't get very much love.

However, this is something that still would be really helpful: particularly on Programmers, where we routinely get people attempting to circumvent bans and rate limits received on Stack Overflow. We have no idea whether a person is actually banned or they just had a momentary lapse of reason, and we waste a lot of time trying to figure it out with very little confidence.

There was a proposal to [prevent migrations when the post owner is banned on the destination site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102293/block-migration-if-user-is-suspended-question-blocked-at-destination), but as I understand it, this only blocks migrations for people manually suspended (something we can already see by just looking at the user's profile on the destination site).

So in lieu of getting limited moderation privileges or blocks on migration for non-public bans, I propose a different feature: when a person gets suspended, rate limited, or low-quality banned on one site, annotate their connected accounts.

This way, moderators can see that a person is banned on the destination site before mistakenly being a party to a ban circumvention.

How about it?

Comment: Honestly, I'd like to just extend the other proposal to include question blocks anyway.

Comment: @GraceNote it does

Comment: @Marc Ooh, excellent

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The core issue here seems to be the abusive "I can't ask any more, so I'll ask my question on a similar site, in the hope it is migrated".

This is already in place, although it isn't very common; in the case illustrated (programmers.SE), it has "fired" 3 times (on 2 questions), so it is working. To illustrate, [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118693) and [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/119399/codeigniter-controller-function-in-a-view) were closed **with migration to StackOverflow**. StackOverflow rejected them (because the user is blocked), so they ended up just as "off topic" (without any migration).

If there are examples of it *not* catching a block, please let me know.

A few of the migration rules are skipped if it is a ♦ moderator clicking the button, however: the "is the user suspended or blocked from asking" is **always** applied.

Comment: That's good to know. We had a couple of cases where we questions why the user had posted on Programmers and they admitted they were banned on SO so we didn't migrate. We were wondering if we should make the "comment and don't migrate" the rule :). Now we can go back to business as usual.

Comment: Yeah wow: I guess we've all been super careful not to circumvent the ban that we never triggered it. Thanks!

Comment: Pinged you in chat, but for the sake of keeping it one place, we have reason to believe, based on the user's comments, that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167988/how-to-have-liferay-portlet-plugin-api-library-back) shouldn't have been migrated.

Comment: @Mark that user is *not* currently blocked. Maybe they have improved their standing since that time?