# Migration failure

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration

[This question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16558/how-to-open-trace-files) was marked to be migrated Stack Overflow, but both times I closed it it simply closed as off-topic. The first time there was another vote to migrate, then I re-opened and did it again with the same result.

Bug? Or some quality check I am unaware of?

***Update***: By contrast, [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16562/how-to-convert-10-tablet-code-design-compatible-to-9-and-7-tablet-in-android) migrated just fine.

Comment: there was a feature implemented recently to block migration in some cases: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112598/165773

Comment: @Al feedback to moderators is supported next build

Comment: @MarcGravell: Hawesome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll check the log, but: questions can be rejected at the receiving site for a number of reasons, including:

- OP is suspended or blocked from asking
- no valid tags

Here we go:

> Question owner is blocked from asking questions

and sure enough, looking at their account on SO it is indeed blocked.

The OP has triggered the low quality filters enough to prevent them asking a question on SO. This check is to prevent people asking elsewhere hoping it will be migrated...

Comment: Marc - moderator migrations should override the valid tags check (Al being an Android mod)

Comment: Well, "no valid tags" will be a tough one. By and large these should be tagged `android` at SO, but `android` is black-listed at Android.SE.

Comment: @ChrisFbut not the first ;p I'm checking the log, anyhow...

Comment: Well, the OP seems to have [valid account on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/users/730876/gnanam-r)

Comment: @ShadowWizard actually, no; they don't - not for asking questions, at any rate

Comment: Marc - I would hope not the first :) Could moderators get feedback for the blocked case>?

Comment: @ChrisF that sounds reasonable; adding that to my list

Comment: Makes sense, and generally I'm in favor of such checks. I agree with ChrisF that it'd be nice to get some feedback when a migration fails because of it (or you're going to keep getting questions like this).

Comment: Tangential: Would it be worth leaving a comment on that question explaining why it couldn't be migrated?

Comment: @AlEverett - I would. The OP probably knows full well that they've been banned and I would bet they are trying to circumvent the ban. Adding a comment will let them know they've been rumbled. On the other hand not telling them will get them question banned on Android too if all their questions are closed :)

Comment: @ChrisF: Not feeling evil today. I'll leave a note.

Comment: @ChrisF feedback is supported next build

Comment: I just wanted to mention that I have seen this in action and it works great. We've got a guy at Android whose four questions have all been closed as off-topic, the latest couldn't be migrated because he's blocked from questions at [so] (and is well on his way to another question block at [android.se]).