# If a migration is rejected, an error message appears briefly and then vanishes

Tags: bug, migration, moderator-tools, post-ban

I attempted to migrate a [question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/21139/) from Arduino SE to Stack Overflow, because it seemed more relevant there.

The migration appeared to succeed however someone noticed afterwards that it was not on SO. After lengthy discussion and testing, it appears that the author of the question was blocked from asking questions on SO, and that this error message appeared very briefly (for around 2 seconds) after the migration.

[image: Cannot ask questions]

Despite the "close box" in the red error message, the message self-dismisses after 2 to 3 seconds. If you are distracted momentarily you don't notice it.

Also on the question history, there is no obvious indication that the question did not in fact migrate:

[image: Non-migrated question]

It appears that *Community* locked the question before migrating, then when it failed unlocked it again. It would be helpful if:

- The error box stayed on the screen until dismissed (ie. until you notice it)
- The log shows the reason why the question was unlocked (eg. "Migration failed: question owner is blocked from asking questions")

As it is, quite a bit of time has been spent deducing why this question was not migrated.

Comment: related: [Annotate user accounts network-wide when they get rate-limited or banned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112598/165773)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think “question owner is blocked from asking questions” is something we want to make public. (Though admittedly it can be inferred if you know how the system works — instance rejection happens only if the user isn't allowed to post questions on the target site.) It would be worth including in the moderator-only timeline however.

The public history and the public timeline do show the expected events: the migration is performed (which involves locking the question on the source site), and then the migration is rejected (which involves unlocking the question). I don't see anything that supports the claim that “the migration appeared to succeed”. To a casual user, it looks like the migration wasn't performed at all (I've had my share of complaints “why did you close this question instead of migrating it?”). To an observant user who's familiar with the trappings, the scenario is clear [but we try not to draw attention on it](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/758/should-moderators-publicly-point-out-when-a-user-is-blocked-from-asking-question).

Comment: Ah, I asked where to report this issue and it was suggested that I report it here.

Comment: I'm happy to delete the question, but I would like the issue addressed somewhere.

Comment: @NickGammon I wasn't suggesting to delete your meta question. I was responding to your request to include the user-blocked information in the history.

Comment: I see. Well, could it appear in the history if you are a moderator? Or is that a structural issue with the database design?

Comment: `I don't see anything that supports the claim that “the migration appeared to succeed”.` - the question is now listed as "On Hold" and underneath is a box saying "put on hold as off-topic by Nick Gammon♦ 38 mins ago". I suppose on close reading it doesn't say "Migrated to Stack Overflow" but if you migrate things only once a week, you may not be familiar with exactly the wording in the box. I clicked the "Migrate" button, and the question changed its status including the box saying "put on hold as off-topic". You would have to be very familiar with the system to know this actually failed.

Comment: @NickGammon It doesn't say “Migrated to Stack Overflow” because the question is no longer migrated. Migration can only happen in combination with closure as off-topic; if the migration is rejected, the off-topic closure state remains.