# Are moderators of other sites notified about actions taken on a user on another site?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, flags, user-accounts, moderation

I have identified a user that has created a sock puppet account to get around the 50 questions/30 days limit on Stack Overflow.  I flagged him, made my case and this user has been suspended and the accounts merged (rather quickly I might add).

However, I actually identified this same pair of accounts as a *possible* duplicate accounts on another site first.  He has a long history of bad questions there and saw some suspicious activity from the user so I flagged there.  As I did my research, that was when I noticed the unusual activity on Stack Overflow which I felt I needed to act on more urgently.

So in the end, I flagged the same user twice on different sites: first on the other site where my flag is pending and the other on Stack Overflow where the flag was acted on.  I'm not so sure what the mods will see on the other site.

Right now, I see my flag on that user with the links to the duplicate account looking odd since they are now merged on all sites.  It now looks something like: "It appears this user X has a duplicate account as user X..."  The user is only suspended on Stack Overflow (and not on other sites the user was registered with).

**Will moderators of the other site *know* that some actions were taken on some user on another site?**

I imagine there's a central moderator note listing per global account or something but thats only speculation.  When the moderators look at that pending flag, will they immediately see that this account was merged with another?  Or will they see what we see and will have to ask about it with other moderators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no central note list, although there is a private moderator chat room where mods can discuss with each other and find out annotations about trouble makers. It is unclear at this point if there are any plans to introduce a central account system.

The situation you've mentioned happens quite often on related sites (and some times, with hardball users, even on unrelated sites) and granting moderators of such sites read-only access to certain information on other sites is actually a pending feature-request: [Provide read-only status to moderators on other Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105281/provide-limited-observer-mod-status-to-moderators-on-closely-related-sites). Please upvote that request if you agree.

Comment: I think Mark's [other suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112595/annotate-user-accounts-network-wide-when-they-get-rate-limited-or-banned) is much more relevant here.

Comment: @JeffMercado I thought of that, but didn't link to it because it was specific to question bans due to poor quality and Marc solved it differently by including a check at the target site. But you're correct, the underlying idea is the same.

Comment: "Hardball" users? You mean "hardcore"?