# Giving moderators "View deleted content" privileges network-wide

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, privileges, moderator-tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read-only peer-review mode for mods cross-domain](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83500/read-only-peer-review-mode-for-mods-cross-domain)
>   [Provide limited observer-mod status to moderators on closely-related sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105281/provide-limited-observer-mod-status-to-moderators-on-closely-related-sites)

Having had a (hopefully) minor problem on Physics.SE, I asked for some advice and help from other moderators in the chatroom.

Alas, the user had deleted [the content in question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17382/the-multiverse-and-the-2nd-law-of-thermodynamics), so the moderators from other sites couldn't help, only Physics.SE mods and Stack Exchange team members were able to see the deleted post.

Is this use case a sufficiently compelling reason to grant community moderators the power to see deleted content on sites where they are not moderators and do not have 10k?

Comment: Related: [Provide limited observer-mod status to moderators on closely-related sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105281/provide-limited-observer-mod-status-to-moderators-on-closely-related-sites)

Comment: `bother physics mods`

Comment: @Mark: Ah...I didn't find that one and could certainly live with it, and one of the comment there links to [an even older question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83500/read-only-peer-review-mode-for-mods-cross-domain) which is a reasonable duplicate for this. Time to close?

Comment: I don't see how you being a moderator on another site is relevant in this case.

Comment: @dmckee I think all three are distinct and different requests, although they are all attempting to address the same problem (mods could use more privileges to advise each other cross-site): not like any of these requests have garnered a full response anyway :P