# Allow Cross-Site Moderator Access?

Tags: feature-request, moderation, moderator-tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Provide read-only status to moderators on other Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105281/provide-read-only-status-to-moderators-on-other-stack-exchange-sites)

Is there a case to be made for moderators being able to see (read-only) the mod-specific stuff on all the sites?

It's long been established that we don't want diamond mods moderating other sites, but we ask them to help each other out to provide guidance and counsel. Still, we don't give them the tools they need to see what's going on in other sites. Sometimes cross-site research of a problematic user is helpful.

How about read-only mod access (on other sites) for things like flags, annotations, deleted comments, etc?

Comment: Do you believe that this is a distinct issue from what @MichaelMrozek posted?

Comment: This would likely be a lot simpler to implement than any kind of cross-site notification features, and would make the moderating job much easier. This assumes that a problem user on one site is likely to behave poorly on other sites too.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I wasn't trying to restrict it to specific subject groups. Seems to be closer to this (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83500/read-only-peer-review-mode-for-mods-cross-domain) although the reasoning and implementation is different. You folks decide.

Comment: I've definitely had scenarios where the ability to do cross-site research would have been VERY nice. Granted it still got handled, but I'd rather not have to ping all the mods for `<x>.SE` just to have them look at something and copy/paste it to me. I can't think of any way giving a mod for `<x>.SE` read-only access to `<y>.SE` hurts the site and I can think of a lot of ways (some from personal experience) that it could help.

Comment: I've updated the dupe question (with Mark's blessing) to be more general and yet not lose context.  This is now an exact dupe of that.  Go vote for it (or better yet, implement it!).